# Python 2.7 not loading in Cygwin

Tags: python, path, cygwin

I'm having an issued getting my install of python27 to load correctly in Cygwin. My install has 2.6 `(/bin/python@ )` on it, but I'd like the default Python environment to be 2.7 (`/cygdrive/c/Python27/python.exe`). I know how to change my $PATH and all, but when I try to run this 2.7 installation through Cygwin by going to its directory and typing `python` it never loads; I have to end the command with CTRL-c. Is this a Cygwin problem, a Windows problem, or a me problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Invoking python under CygWin on Windows hangs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13588454/invoking-python-under-cygwin-on-windows-hangs)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can find some answers in [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3250749/using-windows-python-from-cygwin).

It is rather a problem of using the Windows version of Python with the Cygwin terminal.

Quick summary:

- for interactive mode, add the -i option
- if you want to see the output of your script, add the -u option.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem with Python 2.7 on Cygwin. Launching Python with -i option did get me  to the interpreter, but it would not allow the use of the "up" cursor key to repeat older commands.

What you need to do is to launch the /bin/bash.exe from a DOS prompt. This will launch the standard Windows console instead the Cygwin console.

[This](https://superuser.com/questions/365132/cygwin-terminals-dont-run-some-native-windows-programs) answer sums it up pretty well.