# Invoking python under CygWin on Windows hangs

Tags: python, cygwin

Installing a new Windows system, I've installed CygWin and 64
bit Python (2.7.3) in their default locations (`c:\cygwin` and
`c:\Python27\python`), and added both the CygWin bin and the
Python directory to my path (in the user variable PATH).  From
the normal command window, Python starts up perfectly, but when
I invoke it from `bash` in the CygWin environment, it hangs,
never giving my the input prompt.

I've done this on other machines, previously, but always with
older versions of Python (32 bits) and CygWin, and with Python
in a decidely non-standard location.  Has anyone else had this
problem, or could someone tell me what it might be due to?

Comment: Very similar: [windows - Python not working in the command line of git bash - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32597209/python-not-working-in-the-command-line-of-git-bash?newreg=2b3bd8a46fe54124b460460afe98180f)

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The problem is that due to the way that the Cygwin terminal (MinTTY) behaves, the native Windows build of Python doesn't realize that stdout is a terminal device -- it thinks it's a pipe, so it runs in non-interactive mode instead of interactive mode, and it fully buffers its output instead of line-buffering it.

The reason that this is new is likely because in your previous Cygwin installation, you didn't have MinTTY, and the terminal used was just the standard Windows terminal.

In order to fix this, you either need to run Python from a regular Windows terminal (`Cmd.exe`), or install the Cygwin version of Python instead of a native Windows build of Python.  The Cygwin version (installable as a package via Cygwin's `setup.exe`) understands Cygwin terminals and acts appropriately when run through MinTTY.

If the particular version of Python you want is not available as a Cygwin package, then you can also download the source code of Python and build it yourself under Cygwin.  You'll need a Cygwin compiler toolchain if you don't already have one (GCC), but then I believe it should compile with a standard `./configure && make && make install` command.

Comment: +1 - switching from Windows Python27 to Cygwin Python32 solved this issue I had as well.

Comment: Thanks.  I can't change the version of Python (without installing 2 versions, one for CygWin, one for everything else), because it is part of our production build chain.  But `python -i` works, and creating an alias in `.bashrc` is probably an acceptable solution.

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9549255/9530) also gives some more suggestions of which I was previously unaware -- running Python with the `-u` command line switch or setting the environment variable `PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1` will change Python's buffering behavior.

Comment: But if you've been locked down and can't install or build the following alias may potentially work for you: `alias python='winpty python.exe'`: https://github.com/git-for-windows/git-sdk-64/pull/35

Answer (score 57):

Try this

```
python -i
```

and yes you will find some glitches here and there !!!

Option `-i` forces an interactive prompt as shown in Python help `python -h` page here.

```
$ python -h
-i  : inspect interactively after running script; 
      forces a prompt even if stdin does not appear to be a terminal;
      also PYTHONINSPECT=x
```

Comment: this works perfectly. It would be better to add some information on `python -i` option in the answer so that others no need to do a `python -h` to figure it out.

Answer (score 11):

I had a similar issue with Mercurial (hg)+OpenSSH, Python and MinTTY, but under MSYS instead of CygWin.  Nonetheless, as far as I can tell, both this and my issue were caused by MinTTY not being to handle applications that uses the native Windows console functions (in an answer here by Adam, he explained it in detail for Python).

For me, I followed the solution found in comment 64 of https://code.google.com/p/mintty/issues/detail?id=56#c64

With the winpty (https://github.com/rprichard/winpty) project compiled and in my path, I was able to run **native** Python (in interactive mode) and Mercurial from the MinTTY shell without special builds or switches (such as `python -i`).  All I need was to append `console.exe` or `console` before the `python` or `hg` command.  For convenience, I added aliases such as `alias hg="console.exe hg"` so I can use the same commands whether I'm in a Linux shell or a Windows MinTTY bash shell.

Also, this solution seems to work for more native applications beyond python and hg.  For example, running `mysql` (with or without `-p`) would have given the same problem (e.g. "hangs" with no input prompt).  Appending `console` to it allowed it to as usual.

Comment: I *finally* got the 50 reputation points to say THANK YOU!.  While the '-i' works in most cases, we have lab software that runs mostly cygwin, but then calls out to a windows python since it needs ctypes.WinDLL.  This win call has an embedded ipython prompt and that was royally messed up on mintty (tabs/arrows didn't work, were all goofy).  This is the easiest and best solution -- worked like a charm.  In bash script, just did "console.exe C:\Python27\python.exe" and now the embed ipython works great!  Was pulling hair out, cause on 64 bit windows, mintty is only terminal game in town.

Comment: Not sure how `python -i` actually manages to change the terminal buffering and read individual characters. It must be doing something clever under the hood. Either way `winpty` was the way to go with my Python _script_ which wasn't so clever.

Comment: Should add that the executable name for `winpty` has now been changed from `console.exe` to `winpty.exe`.

Answer (score 3):

another universal workaround is invoking it via `winpty` https://github.com/rprichard/winpty and this is not really a python specific issue.

Answer (score 2):

According to https://stackoverflow.com/a/9549255/745913 you can also try

```
/cydrive/c/Python27/python.exe -i foo.py
```

Answer (score 1):

For managing non-cygwin locations of different versions of Python in CygWin:

```
$ /usr/sbin/alternatives.exe
```

Use the --install and --config options here, it works the same as `update-alternatives` on a Linux system.
I'm using this along with the `python -i` approach, and it's working well.

I also had to delete the sym-link files in `/usr/bin`first, since they were installed with CygWin's python and not managed via alternatives.exe initially.

Answer (score 0):

My solution involved writing a shell script to run the python app.

```
python file.py "$@" | tee /dev/null
```

That extra tee command (to nowhere) seems to fix the issue.

Answer (score -1):

Reinstall mintty with cygwin setup.  Didn't have to use python -i after that.