# How does Python work on Cygwin?

Tags: python-2.7, windows-7, cygwin, pip

I installed Python 2.7.9 from (https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/), and then Cygwin 2.8.59. But I had problems when installing numpy.
        pip install numpy
        error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat

So I uninstalled python using set-x86.exe (Cygwin installer). Now my commands python and pip are these:

```
    $ which python
    /cygdrive/c/Python27/python
    $ which pip
    /cygdrive/c/Python27/Scripts/pip
```

I could installed numpy using pip, and execute files by "python test.py". I, however, cannot use interactive console. If I type

```
    $python
```

the console freezes and I cannot do anything other than Ctrl+C.
How should I do to use the command, "python"?

Comment: is there a special need to have cygwin alongside python? If not, there are plenty of python distributions for windows. I'm using e.g. pythonxy on windows...

Comment: Actually, there is no need. I just wanted to reduce the number of applications I have to use. I will check pythonxy.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Invoking python under CygWin on Windows hangs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13588454/invoking-python-under-cygwin-on-windows-hangs)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
cygstart /cygdrive/c/Python27/python.exe
```

According to this question: [Using Windows Python from Cygwin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3250749/using-windows-python-from-cygwin)

cygwin is just going to hang because windows doesn't think that the cygwin command 'Python' means interactive console, and will not flush the buffer as if it were an interactive console.

Comment: It worked, but executing "cygstart /cygdrive/c/Python27/python.exe" and "python" makes interactive console start on another console but not Cygwin.