# Get python progress bars to behave properly in cygwin

Tags: python, cygwin, progress-bar

I'm running anaconda python in `cygwin`. When I use `keras` and `chainer` from a normal command prompt, they both print out progress bars to show the status of a training run and update them in place.

However, in cygwin, I get a new line for each step making the output unreadable. Is there any fix for this?

This might be related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3250749/using-windows-python-from-cygwin) question that says: "all Cygwin pty-based terminals (mintty, rxvt and xterm) are recognized as pipes by Windows, not as the console".

Comment: I'm not familiar with keras or chainer, but if you haven't already, try running them with [winpty](https://github.com/rprichard/winpty).  I alias a lot of the Windows console-based programs I use from Cygwin (e.g. `docker`) to always run under `winpty`.

Comment: I'm actually SSHing in from a macbook so `winpty` isn't an option :(

Comment: I don't fully understand why but ok, that doesn't mean you can't use winpty.  It's just an executable like any other, but it puts a layer between a Windows program and Cygwin such that it thinks it is on a console and behaves appropriately.  It shouldn't make a difference that you happen to be accessing the Cygwin shell via SSH.